# XSLT 2.0 ul in test expression after axis

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Using this code the 'ul' element wil not trigger the "whatever" template.

```
<xsl:when test="self::p|table|box|example|fig|figure|ol|para|ul" >
        <xsl:call-template name="whatever" />
</xsl:when>
```

Seperating it however, makes it work just fine:

```
<xsl:when test="self::p|table|box|example|fig|figure|ol|para or self::ul" >
        <xsl:call-template name="whatever" />
</xsl:when>
```

Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self::p|table|box|example|fig|figure|ol|para|ul
```

means the same as

```
self::p | child::table | child::box |  ....etc etc....
```

You need to specify the axis on each node test individually, it isn't "distributive" over the `|`.

An alternative and possibly more succinct way to do the same test in XPath 2.0 might be

```
name() = ('p', 'table', 'box', 'example', .....)
```

though that's not quite the same because `self::example` only matches *element* nodes named example, whereas `name() = 'example'` would also match other node types such as attributes.